# NullPointer Exception Servlet request dispatcher

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-security, servlet-listeners

My Webproject code is deployed on weblogic 12c server.
Whenever I call the Home.jsp page which in turn calls a servlet it gives the following error.
Sometimes however the page Home.jsp does load and some times throws error .

Home.jsp calls the Home Servlet and then diospatcher redirects

```
Pas[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '16' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' 10/12/15 01:39:51  ERROR com.att.first.firststatusreports.servlet.HomeServlet doGet - Error occured!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.faces.context.ApplicationMap.get(ApplicationMap.java:97)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.getInstance(ApplicationAssociate.java:247)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.getCurrentInstance(ApplicationAssociate.java:277)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getBeanManager(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:228)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:235)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ChainTypeCompositeELResolver.getValue(ChainTypeCompositeELResolver.java:94)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:103)
        at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.ELHelper.evaluate(ELHelper.java:32)
        at jsp_servlet.__home._jspService(__home.java:156)
        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:352)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:235)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:567)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:263)
        at com.att.first.firststatusreports.servlet.HomeServlet.doGet(HomeServlet.java:64)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:352)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:235)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3284)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1512)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Comment: If it is a JSP that calls a servlet why on earth are there JSF classes being used?

Comment: Hi Denium jsf classes are not being used..there are certain spring controllers and jstl library

Comment: Have you looked at the stack trace? The `com.sun.faces...` stuff is JSF so why is that being used at all.